# How to store a sum result into a variable in awk script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
{
      for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
      netperf -H 10.0.1.2 -P 0 -l $1 &
      done;
      wait;
} | awk '{ sum = sum + $5 } END {print sum, "Mbps Upstream"}'
```

Comment: You already store it in a variable sum.  What do you want?

Comment: I want to take that value in shell script i used echo ${sum} but it is showing nothing

Answer (score -3, accepted):

awk variables and bash variables are different and unrelated to each other.  awk is a program which has the concept of variable and stores its variables and their values internally.   bash is another program which also has the concept of variable and stores its variables and their values internally.  If you buy a teapot and keep it at your kitchen, this doesn't make me have a teapot at my kitchen.

You may print the awk's sum to stdout, catch it and store it to bash's sum:

```
sum=`{ for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do netperf -H 10.0.1.2 -P 0 -l $1 & done; wait; } | awk '{ sum = sum + $5 } END {print sum}'`
```

Comment: What a lovely stream-of-consciousness answer that contains everything _and_ the kitchen sink, but I suggest you [use the modern `$(…)` command-substitution syntax instead of the fraught `\`…\`` legacy syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), just to be safe and promote good habits.

Comment: I don't know whether you chose to delete your own comments or whether moderators did that for you, but let me address your since-deleted comments, just in case:
(a) Thank you for wishing cancer on me; while it's a bit of a departure from teapots, I'll try to keep an open mind. (b) Yes, your answer was accepted, but that has nothing to do with the validity of what I suggested. (c) I understand that you personally prefer `\`…\`` syntax so as to remain compatible with `tcsh`, but that has nothing to do with a question tagged `bash`.